# application with bluetooth in a lot activity

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I have an application with many activities and I need to add bluetooth support. I have no idea how to go about it. Do it with service or not. Bluetooth for one activity is not a problem, but I do not know how to continue connecting in the next activity without reconnecting. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the BluetoothSPP library. It will save you a lot of headache.

https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-BluetoothSPPLibrary

Comment: I saw this library. Can you explain to me - if I create a connection in eg activity main, can I get access to bluetooth resources in my next activity without having to create another connection only by referring to that already existing in activity main?

Comment: You can open the connection in a custom application class, then all your activities and fragments can refer to that connection

Comment: Could u give me example?

Comment: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Understanding-the-Android-Application-Class

in your custom application class `onCreate` method you will initialise your BluetoothSPP.

Please accept my answer since it solves your problem